# How can Markdown mode follow links?

Tags: markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-mode

I found this today by chance: I visited the help file on `split-string` with `C-h f split-strings`:

> split-string is a compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.
>
> (split-string STRING &optional SEPARATORS OMIT-NULLS TRIM)

except that `subr.el` is underlined like a hyperlink and doing `RET` with point on it opens the source code.

I copied it this section to a Markdown file and the text was still underlined. I did `RET` with point on it and it also opened the source code!

I have these modes active in the document: `[(Markdown ElDoc Wrap Fill)]`. If I type the same characters as in `‘subr.el’` (copy-pasting the quotes, which I don't have in my keyboard), it is not highlighted and `RET` does not follow the link.

Including hyperlinks like this one in Markdown is the one thing where I see org mode as superior to markdown mode.

Is it possible to add my own links to other files in markdown mode?

**Update**: The ability to follow the link with `RET` is lost when killing and yanking the text that contains `‘subr.el’.`, or closing and opening the buffer for the file, so I believe this is some special ability in Emacs that comes from copying text from a documentation file and not a feature of Markdown mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`markdown-follow-thing-at-point` (`C-c C-o`) and also `markdown-follow-link-at-point` will follow links. If you have a link like `[filelink](/path/to/file.md)` then calling one of the above functions while cursor is on the markdown link will take you to the file.

Comment: Yes, both work. I checked that the ability to follow the link is lost in some cases and I updated the question. Do you know what's the feature that makes Emacs follow the link copied from the documentation with `RET`?

Comment: It's much easier to link to info files via org mode -- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445285/org-mode-embed-links-to-info-files) SE discussion. I'm not sure how to do it in straightforward fashion with markdown.

Comment: I agree with you and I use Org mode a lot, but for just text I prefer markdown.

Comment: `markdown-do` also works! Bound to `, RET` in spacemacs.